# Radiant intensity of a (non lambertian) emitter, given its radiance function

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

Given a surface emitting radiation according to some radiance function $L\left(\theta,\phi\right)$, what is the radiant intensity of the source?

This question came after reading Robert Boyd's book "Radiometry and the Detection of Optical Radiation".

Boyd defines the radiant intensity as

> The radiant intensity, $I$,  is the flux per unit angle emitted by an entire source in a given direction; in SI system, its unit is Watt per steradian.

> The radiance $L$ is the flux per unit projected area per unit solid angle leaving a source or, in general, any reference surface; in SI, its unit is Watt per meter² per steradian.

To calculate the radiant intensity of the source, I guess I first need to integrate $L$ over a general infinitesimal solid angle $\omega$ contributed by a small patch of the source of area $\delta a$:
$$I_{\delta a} = \iint_{\omega} L\left(\theta,\phi\right)\mathrm{d}\Omega \tag{*}\label{*}$$
and then to integrate this quantity over the whole area of the emitter's surface:
$$I=\iint_A I_{\delta a}\mathrm{d}A\tag{**}\label{**}$$
But I am not sure about this appraoch, since the units of $I$ I get in $\eqref{**}$ are Watt×meter² per steradian, which is wrong.

But how then should I take into account the size of the source (a larger surface emits more radiation)?

Another issue is the integration limits for the small solid angle $\omega$ in $\eqref{*}$. If spherical symettry is valid, then what are the starting and ending azimuthal and polar angles? Is it
$$I_{\delta a} = \int_{\phi_0}^{\phi_0+\delta\phi}\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_0+\delta\theta} L\left(\theta,\phi\right)\sin\theta\ \mathrm{d}\theta\ \mathrm{d}\phi $$
?

For an example (again, from Boyd's book):

> A disk of radius $R$ is a non-Lambertian emitter of Radiance $L_0 \cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the surface normal and the direction of observation, as in the picture below.
> Calculate the radiant intensity of the source.
> [image: Non Lambertian emitter]